Invoke empty Spring Boot Projection empty result
I have this Spring Boot Data JPA repository:
  @Query(value = """
                    SELECT .......                                                                                                           
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  ProfileView findByCustomerId(......);

Projection:
public interface ProfileView {

    String getRreference();
}

Make query:
final ProfileView result = profileRepository.findByCustomerId(......);
final String profile = result.getReference();

I get error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ProfileView.getReference()" because "result" is null

I have a empty result from SQL query. Do you know how I can fix this issue? I need to have just a empty String profile without NPE error.

Use Optional
@Query(value = """
                SELECT .......                                                                                                           
        """, nativeQuery = true)
Optional<ProfileView> findByCustomerId(......);

